device-tree entry for an i2c to spi multiplexer that shares logic with a GPIO multiplexer
I have the following setup (from external; this cannot be changed):
        +------+
  I2C   | I2C  |--------------------- Device 0
--------|  to  |------------ Device 1    | MISO0
        | SPI  |--- Device 2    | MISO1  |
        +------+       | MISO2  |        |
           |           |        |        |
           | MISO  +-------------------------+
           |       |           GPIO          |
           +-------|           MUX           |
                   |                         |
                   +-------------------------+
  GPIO[0:1]                     |
--------------------------------+

In words: There is an I2C-to SPI bridge that is used to communicate with three devices. All SPI signals (MOSI, CS, SCLK) are directly connected to this bridge, except for MISO.
For some reason, the MISO pins to the bridge are multiplexed using a separate GPIO multiplexer.
If it were only for the bridge, the device-tree setup would be fairly straightforward:
i2c_to_spi_brigde: some_device {
    compatible = "...";

    device-0 {
        // ...
    };

    device-1 {
        // ...
    };

    device-2 {
        // ...
    };
};

However, I'm not sure how to incorporate the GPIO multiplexer in this scheme. From all that I have read about gpio-mux and pinctrl, the multiplexed device (in this example, devices 0-2) must also be a child of the mux (in this example, the GPIO MUX). However, the devices 0-2 are already children of the I2C to SPI node.
Is it therefore possible to map the setup I have shown into a device-tree, or is there some form of custom driver necessary?
Edit: The part number for the I2C to SPI bridge is SC18IS602B

I assume you will need to write a custom I2C slave device, SPI host controller device driver for this device since the device select number needs to go both to the I2C device and the GPIO multiplexer. But the custom driver can specify and use the GPIO multiplexer in the same way as the "spi-mux.c" driver, using the "mux-controls" device tree property to hold the phandle of the "gpio-mux" device tree node, and calling devm_mux_control_get (or mux_control_get) in the i2c driver's probe handler to get a pointer to the mux controller.

And for GPIO muxer it sounds like you want to use gpio-latch driver. Have you checked that?

If there is an existing driver for the I2C to SPI controller, it may be possible to utilize that to do the heavy lifting, and drive that from your custom SPI controller.

… Although since there does not seem to be a function to get an SPI controller from a firmware node, another option would be to drive the existing I2C to SPI slaves directly from the custom SPI controller. So the original I2C-to-SPI controller would have dummy child nodes for each slave, and the custom SPI controller would have the real child nodes for each slave and have some way to map the real child nodes to the I2C-to-SPI controller's dummy child nodes (e.g. an array of phandles).

The part number is SC18IS602B. Haven't looked at gpio-latch but it looks promising. There is a kernel driver for the bridge https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/spi/spi-sc18is602.c and it's not too heavy so the best way forward may actually to modify the drivers as I think the both of you suggest

If you wish to notify person about your comment reply, use @user in it. And please update your post with the above information being added, instead of the commenting here.

I didn't suggest modifying the drivers. I suggested wrapping the devices in another driver.
